# Running interactive commands with haskell turtle library

Tags: haskell, haskell-turtle

I am trying to run an interactive command with haskell turtle library like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env stack
-- stack --install-ghc runghc --package turtle
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
import Turtle
main = procs "python" [] empty
```

(I also tried shells function but it does not work either.)
When I run it nothing hapens:

```
$ ./turtleTest.hs
$
```

But if I change "python" command to "ls" it works.

How can I run an interactive command like python repl with turtle library?

Comment: You know about `System.Process`, right? Specifically `callProcess "python" []`.

Comment: and in a turtle context: `view $ liftIO $ callProcess "python" []`

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks @ja

Comment: Or even better in Turtle (if you don't want to see the `()` being printed out after the interactive process exits): `sh $ liftIO $ callProcess "python" []`

Answer (score 2):

Here's a complete working example extracted from comments.
Tu run interactive process via Turtle you can do something like this:

```hs
#!/usr/bin/env stack
-- stack script --resolver lts-14.20 --package turtle --package process
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import System.Process (callProcess)
import Turtle (sh, liftIO)

main :: IO ()
main = sh $ liftIO $ callProcess "python" []
```

Comment: Why not `main = callProcess "python" []` directly?

Comment: You could do that. But my usecase was to execute it withing the context of larger script which already contains Turtle's Shell actions.

Answer (score 0):

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Turtle.Prelude (proc, procs, shell, shells)

main :: IO ()
main = do
  procs "ls" [] mempty         --(without ExitCode)
  procs "ls" ["-la"] mempty    --(without ExitCode)
  proc "pwd" [] mempty         --(with ExitCode)
  proc "ls" ["-la"] mempty     --(with ExitCode)

  shells "ls -la" mempty       --(without ExitCode)
  shell "pwd" mempty           --(with ExitCode)
  shell "ls -la" mempty        --(with ExitCode)
```